# Sqlite DB backup and Encryption

Tags: android

How to take periodic Backup of Sqlite DB in andorid to Sd card and how to encrypt my database on Sd card?

Comment: do you got any solution

Comment: In my case i was storing database in SD card. So i copied and encrypted DB then deleted original one.

Comment: How you did this any sample pls

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a whole file backup you can try Conceal https://github.com/facebook/conceal/. It has an easy to use API for encrypting data.